# Make an ASCII star pattern with asterisks in Java

Tags: java, oop

How to make pattern like this

[image: Star pattern]

validate number must be odd number

( * ) right to the left by input odd number

this is my code so far

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Patern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int z;
        int a,b;

        do 
        {
            System.out.print("Input Odd Number : ");
            z= input.nextInt();
        }
        while (z %2 == 0);//validate input number    

        for(a=1;a<z;a++)
        {
            for(b=1; b<=z;b++)
                if (b==1 || a==z|| a==b)
                {
                    System.out.print(" * "); 
                }
                else if (b==2 || a==z|| a==b)
                {
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println(" * ");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You have code, what specifically about it do you need help with?

Comment: in my code ouput is'nt like the example picture

Comment: What debugging have you done? Again, what specifically are you asking about? "Debug my entire program" isn't an appropriate question here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        draw(11);
    }

    public static void draw(int n){
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if(i==0 || i==j || i == n-1 || i ==(n-1)/2 || i == n-j-1 || j==0 || j==n-1 || j == (n-1)/2){
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code dump answers with no explanation don't help anyone; especially when the question is little more than a code dump itself.

Comment: Last and before last line you should not do println you should just do print

Comment: im explaining now

Comment: and you should add a println() after the first for i think it will work after

Comment: thank you very much this is solved my problem